# Python 'e' notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-notation

I am trying to use `1e6` to return 1000000, but I need to set the '6' to a variable. But

```
units = int(6)
1e(units)
```

gives me a syntax error. The python reference docs have no details on how to use variables instead of ints to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

The `e` notation is just short for 10 raised to a power, so you can do something similar

```
>>> units = 6
>>> 10 ** units
1000000
```

Or more generally

```
def e(base, exp):
    return base * 10 ** exp

>>> e(1, 6)    # 1e6
1000000
>>> e(2.5, 6)  # 2.5e6
2500000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as CoryKramer suggested, heres other way below:

```
>>> units = 6
>>> float(f'1e{units}')
1000000.0
```